# List of events, that cause React component to re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know, what are events, that cause React component to re-render.

I couldn't find full list anywhere, it'd be great if someone writes the list of events, that cause React component to re-render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always find the following reference website helpful.

http://reactcheatsheet.com/

Filter by lifecycle events, and you can see the places where setState will trigger a rerender.

__

Update: you now have to filter by "misc"

Comment: How about, neither `props` nor `state` of component change, but parent component re-renders, does it cause child to re-render too? Can it be prevented by `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Comment: If a parent re-renders, then all of it's children re-render. You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` as a mechanism to prevent rendering on any component (well, besides stateless functional components as they don't have lifecycle hooks).

Answer (score 1):

React component is re-rendered when `setState()` is called or when `props` change. You can also force re-render with `forceUpdate()`

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

> By default, when your component's **state** or **props change**, your
> component will re-render. However, if these change implicitly (eg:
> data deep within an object changes without changing the object itself)
> or if your render() method depends on some other data, you can tell
> React that it needs to re-run render() by calling **forceUpdate()**.